# how to configure hangfire which uses two different database in console application?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am using HangFire Nugget package to schedule the jobs in asp.net core console application.

Now I have scenario where the data is fetching from different database and updating in one database? I tried but I am not able to get it clearly

i cant call that database from the stored procedure.
i should call it from c#.

If the database is in another server how can i call it?

i am fresher new to this programming i am not getting i request please explain me with simple code

Comment: Hangfire is used only for scheduling jobs. It does not know how to connect to database. So ... Yes you need to write C# code to read and write data to database. You need to learn about ADO.NET for that..... There is no difference in code whether your database is in local server or another server.

Comment: i mean how to configure the hangfire to read the data from two different databases

Comment: You need to scheduled job on SQL Server using Hangfire? and the job involves reading data from more than one database?

Comment: yes exactly i need to schedule the job in sql